# LINQ Guarantees Ordering with SelectMany?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of ordered enumerables `IorderedEnumerable<T>[] foo` and I want to flatten it so that the ordered enumerables of `foo` are concatenated together in the order they are stored in the array.

For example {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6}} => {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

Can I do this by `IOrderedEnumerable<T> bar = foo.SelectMany(x => x);`, or does LINQ not guarantee how order is handled when flattening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lists (represented by `IEnumerable<T>` in .net) along with two operations form a monad, which must obay the [monad laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Monad_laws). These two operations are given different names in different languages, the wikipedia article uses Haskell which calls them `return` and `>>=` (called 'bind'). C# calls `>>=` `SelectMany` and does not have a built-in function for `return`. The names are unimportant however and what matters is the types. Specialised for `IEnumerable<T>` these are:

```
Return :: T -> IEnumerable<T>
SelectMany :: IEnumerable<T> -> Func<T, IEnumerable<U>> -> IEnumerable<U>
```

`Return` simply returns a 1-element sequence containing the given element e.g.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Return<T>(T item)
{
    return new[] { item };
}
```

`SelectMany` is already implemented as `Enumerable.SelectMany`:

```
public static IEnumerable<U> SelectMany<T, U>(IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<T, IEnumerable<U>> f) { ... }
```

`SelectMany` takes an input sequence and a function which generates another sequence for each item of the input sequence and flattens the resulting sequence of sequences into one.

Restating the first two monad laws in C# we have:

**Left identity**

```
Func<T, IEnumerable<U>> f = ...
Return(x).SelectMany(f) == f(x)
```

**Right identity**

```
IEnumerable<T> seq = ...
seq.SelectMany(Return) == seq
```

By the right identity law, `SelectMany` must flatten each sequence generated by the `Func<T, IEnumerable<U>>` according to the order of the input elements.

Assume it flattened them in reverse order e.g.

```
new[] { 1, 2 }.SelectMany(i => new[] { i, -i }) == new[] { 2, -2, 1, -1 }
```

then

```
var s = new[] { 1, 2 }
s.SelectMany(Return) == new[] { 2, 1 } != s
```

which would not satisfy the right-identity law required.

Comment: So is that a yes or a no?

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ - The documentation for `SelectMany` doesn't explicitly guarentee it (although it does refer to 'flattening' the resuling sequences) but the current implementation does and failing to do so would violate the monad laws so yes, I think you can rely on it maintaining the order.

Answer (score 19):

All LINQ to Objects methods (except, obviously, `OrderBy()` and `ToDictionary()`) will preserve source ordering.

Comment: Even `OrderBy` implements a stable sort on LINQ to objects :)